# How to pass data to a modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a menu that has menu items generated from a foreach loop. Each menu item has an eventname and an edit button for that particular event here is the code that generates the menu:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
$eventid=$row['id'];
$name=$row['name'];

echo '<li class="nav-item">';
 echo '<a class="nav-link" href="#">'.$name.'</a><button class="removebutton" eventid="'.$eventid.'" style="vertical-align:middle;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editevent"><span>Edit</span></button>';
 echo '</li>';
 echo '<hr />';
}
}
```

When a user clicks on the remove button a modal pops up. I want the user to be able to edit that specific record based on its $eventid from the database. It would be even better if the existing values can be passed onto the fields of the modal form.

Answer (score 1):

if you using bootstrap modal, then you can do the trick like this.

you set your value that you want to pass in attribute, and whenever user click you set the modal value, then show the modal.
like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#editBtn").click(function(event) {
    let el = event.target;

    let name = el.getAttribute('data-name');
    let registered = el.getAttribute('data-registered');

    $("#name").val(name);
    $("#registered").val(registered);

    $("#editModal").modal("show");
  })
})
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/151896/

Answer (score 0):

You can read eventid attribute of button clicked as shown in below code

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click", "button.removebutton", function(){
      var eventId = $(this).attr("eventid");
      alert(eventId); // user this event id for edit purpose
      // in modal form, you can assign event id to any input or any other html element.
     // suppose you have input with id='modalEventId' then use below code
     $('#modalEventId').val(eventId);
  });
});
```

Comment: Instead of the alert function is there a way I can pass these as values in the modal form?

Comment: you can put `eventId` to any html element in modal form. you can use id, class or attribute selectors to get the html element and put event id in it. check this for details of jquery selectors https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: you can tell me modal form name or id and the element to which event id need to be attached

Answer (score 0):

try this...!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".removebutton").on("click",function() {
      var event_id = $(this).attr("eventid");
      console.log(event_id); //based on this id you can get event detail and edit it
 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below to achieve whatever you want.

```
$("button.removebutton").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var eventId = $(this).attr("eventid");

        //fetch the data from server

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/url",
            data: {eventId:eventId},
            success: function (response) {
                //Show the popup
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from attr eventid and print on your modal it can be hidden field or text.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('button.removebutton').on("click", function(){
     var eventId = $(this).attr("eventid");
     $('#event_id').val(eventId);
 });
});

<input type="text" value="" id="event_id">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an unique id for each menu item which connects to an unique modal by a specific id. 
Change data-target in  your menu item link as below to get specific modal for each.

`echo '<a class="nav-link" href="#">'.$name.'</a><button class="removebutton" eventid="'.$eventid.'" style="vertical-align:middle;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editevent-'.$eventid.'"><span>Edit</span></button>';`

In modal,
 assuming $eventid variable can access from outside of the loop..

```
    <div class="modal" id="editevent-<?=$eventid ?>" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-body">
        <!--Modal body text goes here....
        here will have the form with existing input values to be edited related to given $eventid(corresponding $row data).eg:
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name"
                                                   value=<?=$row['name]?>/>-->

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" data-id="<?=$eventid;?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-update">Submit
                                        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in script,
Updated input values will be submitted to the database

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('button.btn-update').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('name', $("input[name='name']").val());
            data.append('address', $("input[name='address']").val());
            data.append('email', $("input[name='email']").val());
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            data.append('id', id);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "url to form data submit",
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('success');
                },
                error: function (reject) {
                    console.log(reject);
                }
            });
            $('#editevent-' + id).modal('toggle');
            return false;
    });
});
```